# Mail address of the sender - with contact form

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5.1

I just ask for a little help please, because I'm beginner with Laravel, and I have a problem with my contact form:

When I receive mail, it does not write me the email address of the sender. For example, if in the contact form (in input type="email"), the visitor writes this email address: **test@test.fr**

In my inbox, his email address is not displayed. it shows me my adress mail to me. What for ? And if I click reply, I answer to myself ...
image :
http://www.creerwebsite.com/medias/upload/aaab.png

In the above image, De: That shall have to display the email address of the sender, not mine...

In fact, I noticed that that shows me the e-mail address of my .env

MAIL_USERNAME=aaa@bbb.fr

MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword

To debug, I tried to change this e-mail address which is in my .env. and that shows me the other address which is informed in my .env. I shall wish that in my receptions of e-mail, whether it is the e-mail address of the sender which is displayed, not my e-mail address which is in my .env. How to fix this please?

My code:

```html
<?php
/**
* Traitement du formulaire de contact
*/
public function executeContact(ContactFormRequest $request)
{
 $data = [
  'receiver' => 'aaa@bbb.fr',
  'sender' => $request->get('nom'),
  'sender_email' => $request->get('email'),
  'exp_message' => $request->get('message')
 ];

 //dd($data);


 // Mail::send() prend 3 params :
 // _vue(s) utilisée(s) pour le modèle de corps e-mail
 // _tableau de données qui sera mise à la disposition du modèle e-mail
 // _closure qui donne l'occasion de définir les options :
 // from('expéditeur@envoyeur.fr'), to('destinataire@receveur.fr'), subject('sujet'), ...
 Mail::send( 
    ['emails/contact', 'emails/contact-text'],
    ['data' => $data],
    /*[
     'sender' => $request->get('nom'),
     'sender_email' => $request->get('email'),
     'exp_message' => $request->get('message')
    ],*/
    function($message) use ($data) {
     $message->from($data['sender_email'])  // ici ça ne marche pas
       ->to($data['receiver'])  // ici ça marche
       ->subject('Sujet test');
     //$message->attach(public_path() . '/medias/images/fleche-haut.png');
    }
   );

 return \Redirect::route('contact')->with('message', 'Merci pour votre message !');
}
```

Thank youy

Comment: What information can you see, if you try to: var_dump($data) ? (or dd($data))

Comment: try this: Mail::send(['emails/contact', 'emails/contact-text'],['data' => $data], function ($message) use ($data) {
               $message->from($data["sender_email"],'Name optional');
               $message->to($data['receiver'], 'Your page name')->subject($data["subject"]);
           });

Comment: Ok. I have test this code:
http://www.creerwebsite.com/medias/upload/c.png

I wrote this :
http://www.creerwebsite.com/medias/upload/c2.png

In my email box, It is still my email (which is in my .env) which is sending
http://www.creerwebsite.com/medias/upload/c3.png

Why?
thanks

Comment: So you are using live as smtp server, for sending emails right ? It looks like, they disallow sending emails from different email address than one tied to your user account (in case you pretended to be someone else). Did you think about using transactional email services like [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com) or [Mailgun](http://mailgun.com) ?

Comment: I do not know Mandrill and Mailgun . My config/app : http://www.creerwebsite.com/medias/upload/app.png. My .env : http://www.creerwebsite.com/medias/upload/env.png

Comment: Here is a very basic tutorial, you will be able to complete under 10-20 minutes. http://jamie.sh/tutorials/7/setting-up-mailgun-with-laravel-5 so you can send emails with mailgun.

Comment: ok thank. I'll go look. I will return about whether resolved or not.

Comment: i have test : 'driver' => 'mail', it works. it's better than smtp. locally with Wamp it does not. but online it works. Thank you

Comment: well i'm glad you resolved your problem